# I have Insatlled every dependencies in IPython.Stil it showing Error like Below

Tags: ipython

In [3]: ipcluster start -n 4
  File "", line 1
    ipcluster start -n 4
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/ipython-user/2011-April/007477.html, you may be trying to run command-line scripts from Python.  You should try running ipcluster from the command line.